# How to execute command in background with case statement in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, script, process

I'm in trouble: my script doesn't work as expected :)

Part of my code:

```
readarray operations < operations.list
### lalala
for ((i=0; i<${#operations[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "Perform ${operations[$i]}"
    case ${operations[$i]} in
            "dog rex" )
                    command1 & ;;
            "cat sam" )
                    command2 & ;;
            * )
                    command3 ;;
    esac
done
```

**operations.list** file looks like

```
 dog rex
 cat sam
 frog mike
 monster jack
```

I expect that **command1**, **command2** and **command3** must be execute in background, but it's not. What am I do wrong?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Please [edit] and include the rest of the script.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax. Are you sure "command{1,2,3}" do not complete before you check that they're running?

Comment: **Why** the downvote? @DavidPostill: I do not think there is any need to add more info.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Because I wanted something I could actually test ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the elements of your array are *dog\n cat\n, frog\n, monster\n*. So your *case* statement should be:

```
case ${operations[$i]} in
        dog\n)
                echo "Step dog" & wait ;;
        cat\n)
                echo "Step cat" & wait ;;
        *)
                echo "Step all else" &  wait ;;
esac
```

Strictly speaking, I think it is a bad idea to discount the possibility that an innocent soul may have dropped a space or two after each entry, so that I would rather use:

```
case ${operations[$i]} in
        dog*)
                echo "Step dog" & wait ;;
        cat*)
                echo "Step cat" & wait ;;
        *)
                echo "Step all else" &  wait ;;
esac
```

but then, YMMV.

Comment: And you were absolutely right!